# Remove Route from HttpRouteCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I am using the attribute routing included in WebAPI 2.0, but cannot figure out how to remove a route based on certain conditions.  I map all routes using the `MapHttpAttributeRoutes`, and then I would like to remove a specific route using the next line of code.

```
        // enable attribute routing support
        httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // expose the flag routes only if required
        if (DisableFlagEndpoint)
        {
            httpConfiguration.Routes.Remove(FlagsController.RouteName);
        }
```

But this throws a `NotSupportedException`.  How does one remove a route ?  If not, is there another way to achieve this ?

Comment: ineresting..what is your exact scenario for which you are requiring to do this?

Comment: I would like to disable/remove routes per environment.  For example, a test route entrance is only required on dev machines, so I would like to only enable it there and disable it in all other configurations.  I'm guessing I will have to write a quick Filter to achieve this though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like WebAPI 2.1 introduces the ability to do this with `IgnoreRoute()`.  http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/releases/whats-new-in-aspnet-web-api-21#ignoreroute

```
// disable the flag routes if required
if (DisableFlagEndpoint)
{
    httpConfiguration.Routes.IgnoreRoute("Flags", "api/flags/{*paths}");
}

// enable attribute routing support
httpConfiguration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```